# Python imaplib delete's 2 emails then crashes

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap, imaplib

***What I am trying to do:***
I want to retrieve emails from gmail, download the email as a text file then delete the original email off the gmail server.

***The Issue:***
The Issue I run into is when I add the delete portion of the code.  So If I don't delete, it will pull down all the emails I want and save them as text files.  Once I added the delete portion of my code it downloads 2 emails then deletes them off the gmail server then gives the error below on the third.  I can run the script again and it will download another 2 and give the same error on the third.  I can't see what i'm doing wrong, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**The Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getpass, imaplib, email, os
from email.parser import HeaderParser

detach_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/Test/')
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
address = "EMAIL@GMAIL.com"
password = "PASSWORD"
M.login(address, password)

M.select("EMAIL LABEL")

resp, items = M.search(None, "ALL")
items = items[0].split()

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = M.FETCH(emailid, '(RFC822)')
    mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        if part.get_content_subtype() != 'plain':
            continue

        payload = part.get_payload()

        filename = mail["Subject"] + "_gmail.txt"
        filename = filename.replace('FW: ', '').replace(' ', '_').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('__', '_')
        print "FILENAME IS: " + filename

        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

        if (not os.path.isfile(att_path)):
            fp = open(att_path, 'w+')
            fp.write(payload)
            fp.close()

    M.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
    M.expunge()
```

**The Error**

```
 FILENAME IS: email_1_gmail.txt
 FILENAME IS: email_2_gmail.txt
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/user1/Documents/Personal Work/Project/gmail4.py", line 20, in <module>
     mail = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```